# AsEnumerable with range of dates

Tags: vb.net

with my code below I'm able to select row .field ("Objectif) values based on current week and current year from datatable(dt1). how can I do the same by putting a range of date as condition ? example from Sept 01 2014 to Sept 01 2015 .thanks

```
dim ThisWeekTotal = (
            From Row In dt1.AsEnumerable
            Where MyCalendar.GetWeekOfYear(Row.Field(Of DateTime)("date"),
                                           CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek,
                                           DayOfWeek.Sunday) = Currentweek And MyCalendar.GetYear(Row.Field(Of DateTime)("date")) = Currentyear
            Select Row.Field(Of Double)("objectif")
        )
```

Comment: In the `Where` clause: ` datefIeld >= firstDate && dateField <= lastDate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use `<` and `>` with `DateTime` values, so you can do something like:

```
Dim lowerBound As DateTime = ...
Dim upperBound As DateTime = ...

... in the query ...
   Where lowerBound <= Row.Field(Of DateTime)("date") AndAlso
         Row.Field(Of DateTime)("date") < upperBound
```

That's treating `lowerBound` as inclusive and `upperBound` as exclusive, which is *usually* (but not always) a good idea.